# Get values for N objects

Tags: android, database

I need to collect values on an android app.
I'll do my best to explain myself.

Let's say I have a trail with devices, those devices have meters with different units.
I need to get the values of each meter grouped by device.
(Each object have it's own id)

For example: Trail "T" have "D1" and "D2" as devices, each one have 2 meters, so it should retrun a table with this data:

```
T, D1, meter 1, value
T, D1, meter 2, value
T, D2, meter 1, value
T, D2, meter 2, value
```

How can I get this data?

(I hope my explanation helps)

Comment: How are you storing this data?

Comment: "it should retrun a table with this data:" What returns the data?

Comment: Are you writing an app that installs on each device? Or something else?

Comment: consider using Firebase, see my answer

Comment: I did that for tracking location of group of users

Comment: I have data in an array, then each row of the array should be an activity / layout in android.
I need a similar "ViewPager" tool, I tried used "ViewPager" and have managed to create the dynamically screens, but not how to get the data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that. The simipliest way to do that is to use Firebase. But, all devices has to have Internet connection. You will create node in database tree, say, devices, which will contain is of all devices, and, another branch, say, readings. When device is registered (added into group), it should add itself into 'devices' branch, and, when it reads value, it should write those values into 'readings' branch under its name. 
Moreover, you can register listener to be notified whenever some device pushed new data. That database synchronizes automatically with cloud and have cached values.
You can add 'monitor' mode in your app, in which you'll see all devices and last updated values (just read those from database, it will be up to date).
See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data .

Comment: That's not my problem.
I have a solution, perhaps not the best solution, but it works.
My problem is the next:
Imagine that I have an array with 10 rows, then I need to perform 10 screens in Android.
What I need is a generic tool that makes the screens.
Now suppose you have 15 rows in the array, then I need to create 15 screens.
Each screen displays the information in a row of the array.